# Centralize the AOP logging for my microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-aop

I have multiple microservices and have establish AOP logging to log my controller, service, and repository layers. Currently, the same AppAspect class is redundant over all my microservice. Is there a way to centralize this?

A thought : have the AOP class as jar, upload it to some repository (or even AWS S3) and have my microservices depend on those.

Why? : Whenever I want to make a small change on my AOP logs, I have to do it repeatadely accross all microservice.

Any leads would help. Following is my AOP AppAspect class

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AppAspect {
    private String ipAddress = "[NO-IP]";

    @Before("execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.controller..*(..)) " +
            "|| execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.service..*(..)) " +
            "|| execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.repository..*(..))")
    public void logBeforeMethodExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        try {
            // get ip address
            ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
            if (requestAttributes != null) {
                HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
                ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
            }
            // get method name
            String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getPackage().getName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
            log.info("[{}] Started method execution {}", ipAddress, methodName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{} Error in AppAspect {}", ipAddress, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterReturning("execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.controller..*(..)) " +
            "|| execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.service..*(..)) " +
            "|| execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.repository..*(..))")
    public void logAfterMethodExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        try {
            // get method name
            String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getPackage().getName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
            log.info("[{}] Completed method execution {}", ipAddress, methodName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{} Error in AppAspect {}", ipAddress, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.controller..*(..)) " +
            "|| execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.service..*(..)) " +
            "|| execution(* np.com.oskarshrestha.bookstorebackend.repository..*(..))", throwing = "exception")
    public void logAfterMethodExecutionThrows(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) {
        try {
            // get method name
            String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getPackage().getName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
            log.info("[{}] Exception thrown by method execution {} {}", ipAddress, methodName, exception.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{} Error in AppAspect {}", ipAddress, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to look for references or resources but didn't find much lead. Is this even possible?

Comment: Your aspect is flawed to start with, it will fail to log correctly in a multi threaded environment. If you want to log additional information put that in the MDC (through a servlet filter, to extract the IP address for instance) then use a regular logging facility (apparently ou want to trace logging) like the one shipped with Spring, the `CustomizableTraceInterceptor`. Combine that with additional information in the MDC and you can do anything you like.

Comment: MDC is a good solution, but not necessary, if the OP - assuming he wants to stick to his AOP solution - simply uses a thread-local field for the IP address. That way, the aspect is less tightly coupled to SLF4J and can more easily be refactored, if the logging framework is to be switched for any reason. But of course, you are right about Spring offering tools that do not need to be rebuilt by aspects.

Comment: @M.Deinum To keep the question simple I had stripped the unnecessary part of the code. MDC seems promising, will give it a look. Thank you for the help.